# Create custom extensions for NDepend

Tags: ndepend

By looking at the NDepend documentation, I found that you can create procedure in your CQLinq queries (as stated [here](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/cqlinq-syntax#Proc)). I was looking for a way to create custom extensions or procedures that I would be able to use in any queries. Is something exists for that in NDepend ?

Thanks

Comment: Not yet but you can vote from this feature here https://ndepend.uservoice.com/forums/226344-ndepend-user-voice/suggestions/9752604-let-queries-pull-data-from-other-queries